# Backbone testing with theintern.js

Tags: testing, backbone.js, intern

How can I define inside the .js that I want to test?

Better in an example:

This is my test file:

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'intern/order!app/scripts/misc/utils'
], function (registerSuite, assert, Utils) {
    'use strict';
    registerSuite({
        name: 'Utils',

        greet: function () {
            assert.strictEqual(Utils.clearString('/prueba'), '-prueba', 'utils.clearString should return -prueba changing / for -.');
        }
    });
});
```

My file for testing:

```
define(['misc/envConfig'],
    function (EnvConfig) {
        'use strict';
        return {
            clearString: function (string) {
                var from = 'ÃÀÁÄÂÈÉËÊÌÍÏÎÒÓÖÔÙÚÜÛãàáäâèéëêìíïîòóöôùúüûÑñÇç/ ',
                    to = 'AAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOUUUUaaaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuunncc--',
                    mapping = {};

                for (var i = 0, j = from.length; i < j; i++) {
                    mapping[ from.charAt(i) ] = to.charAt(i);
                }

                var ret = [];
                for (i = 0, j = string.length; i < j; i++) {
                    var c = string.charAt(i);
                    if (mapping.hasOwnProperty(string.charAt(i))) {
                        ret.push(mapping[ c ]);
                    } else {
                        ret.push(c);
                    }
                }
                return ret.join('');
            }
        };
    }
);
```

This happend when I run the test:

```
Error: Failed to load module misc/envConfig from /projectFolder/misc/envConfig.js (parent: app/scripts/misc/utils)
    at /projectFolder/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:754:12
    at fs.js:207:20
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Note that the define inside the test file should be in /projectFoler/app/scripts/misc/envConfig.js

I know that envConfig is never used, because I deleted the other functions in this example.

Thank you for your time, and sorry about the poor explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency you have written in `app/scripts/misc/utils` to `'misc/envConfig'` should be `'./envConfig'`.